# shell: running scripts with standard input using input redirection

Tags: bash, shell

I have this script myprogram

```
#!/bin/bash
echo This is the first one ${1}.
echo This is the second one ${2}.
```

and the input file test.txt

```
Hi
Hello
```

and I hope to use input redirection to run the script with input from test.txt, which should output

```
This is the first one Hi.
This is the second one Hello.
```

I'm trying to use

```
./myprogram < test.txt
```

but it's not working. The only thing it printed out is

```
This is the first one
This is the second one
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Your script doesn't ever try to read from standard input, so what you redirect on stdin doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Positional parameters (aka command line arguments) are not related to stdin. Here's an example that uses both:

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/bash
echo "These are the first two arguments: $1 and $2"
read -r first
echo "This is the first input line on stdin: $first"
read -r second
echo "This is the second input line on stdin: $second"

$ ./myscript foo bar < test.txt
These are the first two arguments: foo and bar
This is the first input line on stdin: Hi
This is the second input line on stdin: Hello
```